# Electromotive force of a battery

Tags: batteries, emf

The definitions of electromotive force of a cell that i have studied include:

1.When no current is drawn from a cell,i.e., when the cell is in open circuit, then potential difference between the terminals of the cell is its electromotive force.

2.The electromotive force of a cell is defined as the energy spent or the work done per unit charge in taking a positive charge around the complete circuit of the cell i.e., in the circuit outside the cell as well as in the electrolyte inside the cell.

I do not understand what definition 1 means. I think it is probably refers to the work done in moving the charge inside the cell since in the definition it is said that the circuit is open but then its meaning does not match with definition 2. My question is, what is the actual meaning of definition 1 and how is it even related with definition 2.

Comment: The first is more a description of how to measure it in practice, while the second is a description of its effect.

Answer (score 3):

Think of a battery like this:

[image]

V1 is the voltage produced by the chemical reaction in the battery.  This is the EMF you are asking about.

However, real batteries have this annoying problem of some inevitable resistance that can be thought of as being in series with this voltage source.  If you draw some current from the battery, its voltage goes down because the current time R1 causes a voltage drop.

So how to measure V1 without R1 getting in the way?  Measure the voltage while drawing as little current as possible.  This is the *open circuit* voltage of the battery, and is just V1.

Even a voltmeter draws *some* current, but so little in a practical sense that it can be ignored.  For example, R1 might be 10s of Ohms in a small battery.  The voltmeter's 10 MΩ input resistance is still so large relative to that as to be infinite for our purposes.

Comment: I do not understand how can we measure the potential difference of the cell when no current is drawn from it, i.e., when it is in an open circuit.

Comment: @Mrap: It seems you are confusing measuring a voltage with that voltage doing work.  Voltage is like a force.  You can measure it without the force "doing" anything.

Comment: Does the second definition refer to the external circuit(the circuit connected to the terminals of the cell) or the circuit inside the cell formed by the internal resistance?

Comment: @mrap: Your second definition is just the definition of EMF in general.  A battery is one source of EMF.  By the way, EMF and "voltage" are the same thing.  The correct term is EMF, but we often take a shortcut and say "voltage" because this EMF is always (in electrical engineering anyway) expressed in Volts.

Comment: So basically, the EMF in the second definition is theoretically not exactly equal to the EMF mentioned in the first definition but a very close approximation of it due to the flow of current through the internal resistance. Right?

Comment: @Mrap: #1 isn't a definition, just something about a battery.  It is correct, however.  Note that "open circuit" means no current is flowing.

Comment: Would you say that what i said in the previous comment about approximation is correct?

Comment: @Mrap: No, because your first statement isn't about a approximation.  You say "no current draw", so the battery voltage is the internal EMF exactly.

Comment: Yes that is what i am saying. The EMF in the first case is the exact EMF but in the second case the EMF is approximately equal to the EMF in the first case due to internal resistance which causes a potential drop.

Comment: Hey what happened?

Answer (score 0):

I believe definition 1 becomes clearer when you realize that any battery or cell has a non-zero output impedance. In other words, when you load the cell up and take current, there is a reduction in external voltage but, the EMF that the cell produces internally remains constant but is no longer measurable.

Comment: What do you mean by output impedance?

Comment: Every battery or cell can be modelled as a perfect voltage source in series with a resistor else infinite current would flow on a short circuit and we know that doesn't happen.

Comment: And that resistor's resistance is known as output impedance. Right?

Comment: Quite commonly it is called output impedance, output resistance or even effective series resistance (or ESR).